# Titanium build error on device

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have a serious problem with titanium appcelerator studio build, i cannot build on device due to following error :

> [ERROR] :  An error occurred during build after 1m 35s 521ms
>   [ERROR] :  Failed to install app on device (0xe8008018)
>   [ERROR] :  For some reason the app failed to install on the device. Try reconnecting your device and check your provisioning profile and entitlements.

It happens just after titanium try to install app to device :

> Installing app on device: xxx

Anyone has an idea about it please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that the app wasn't already installed on the device? Can you bring more information?

Comment: Hello, i already uninstalled the app

Answer (score 0):

To run on an iOS device, you need to have a valid signing cert and a valid provisioning profile that has that device's id embedded init.

> Validity is important, as an expired signing cert will also return the
>   same error code (0xe8008018)

You can start up Xcode, visit the Devices window with your device plugged in to see the device console.  That might give you more context than the titanium error logs will.

Follow ups would be:
1. Have you ever been able to build to a device with this project?
2. Have you ever been able to build to this device with this project?

Comment: I have already build this project before (on device and simulator), may be because of sdk update?